# XNA Projected texture in two directions (one is opposite direction)

Tags: xna, shader, hlsl, deferred

I created Projector with:

Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, direction, Vector3.Up);
Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), 1, 1, 2);

I pass to the shader multiplication of these matrices (in shader called View), then in shader I do:

```
float4 proj(float3 Position)
{
    float4 texCoord = mul(float4(Position, 1.0), View);
    texCoord.x = ( (texCoord.x / texCoord.w)/2) + 0.5;
    texCoord.y = (-(texCoord.y / texCoord.w)/2) + 0.5;
    return tex2D(shape, texCoord.xy);
}
```

uvw of texture is Clamped. I use it in light stage of deffered shading. Resulting image (red arrow is the correct direction):
[image](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/746/textureproj.jpg)

What should I do to make it go only in correct direction?

SOLVED:
The problem was back projection wich was simply solved:

```
float4 proj(float3 Position)
{
    float4 texCoord = mul(float4(Position, 1.0), View);
        if(texCoord.z < 0)
            return 0;
    texCoord.x = ( (texCoord.x / texCoord.w)/2) + 0.5;
    texCoord.y = (-(texCoord.y / texCoord.w)/2) + 0.5;
    return tex2D(shape, texCoord.xy);
}
```

Comment: I assume, the green light in the left part is what is wrong. It looks like the light ray is projected in the negative direction. The code snippet you provided does not seem to have anything to do with lighting. Could you add the according code? And in which texture do you store lighting information?

Comment: Solved yesterday, found out it's called back projection (or reverse projection). I just added if statment that checks if texCoord.z is negative to eliminate back projection

Comment: You can add this as an answer to indicate that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is back projection wich is simply solved:

```
float4 proj(float3 Position)
{
    float4 texCoord = mul(float4(Position, 1.0), View);
        if(texCoord.z < 0)
            return 0;
    texCoord.x = ( (texCoord.x / texCoord.w)/2) + 0.5;
    texCoord.y = (-(texCoord.y / texCoord.w)/2) + 0.5;
    return tex2D(shape, texCoord.xy);
}
```